SSRS Report - error in parameter config - An attemp was made to set a data set parameter that is not defined in this dataset
I know this question has been asked to death for the past what 16 years and I feel completely dumb to ask. Cannot figure it out and bet you a dollar I will work out before someone replys with the correct answer.
The error I get:
An attempt was made to set a data set parameter '@QuoteID' that is not defined in this dataset.
I decided to pull my report out into a separate project with a single shared dataset + report. The dataset uses a proc that has a single parameter @QuoteID and for the life of me when I set up a dataset in the report to this shared dataset without first going to the Parameters tab and just closing the report to save it creates the parameter for me as @QUOTE_ID and then in the shared dataset the parameter setting is @QuoteID for the name and [@QUOTE_ID] for the value. And even if I rename the parameter to @QuoteID is still does not work. Am I going mad? Does it have a hangover from something else cached in memory or what??
The only other thing to note if it really matters is the first field in the proc is QUOTE_ID but fields and parameters should not interfere and I should be able to name my proc parameter one way and have a different spelling in my parameter in my report as long as the config is set up correctly which it is well at least it looks right to me but obviously not if is showing this error.

Show you dataset config including the parameters tab and any expressions that are present, also show the header of you SP just in case. I can't visualise what you are seeing from your description.
